# When writing a program to see who the eldest person is out of so many, is there a formula I'm missing?

Tags: loops

It keeps coming up '[name] is the eldest with 0 years'
I'm using a for loop because I have an exam coming up dealing with loops and its simply for studying purposes.

All answers are greatly appreciated!

Conor

```
    System.out.println("How many people are involved?");
    amount = EasyIn.getInt();

    currentage = 0;

    for(index = 1; index <= amount; index++)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter the name of " + index + " person");
        name = EasyIn.getString();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Enter their age please ");
        age = EasyIn.getInt();

        System.out.println();


    if(currentage > age)
        {
            currentage = age;
            maxname = name;
            maxage = age;
        }


    System.out.println("The oldest person is " + maxname + "with the age of " + `               `maxage + " years");

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, we can't help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
currentage=0
if(currentage > age){
    do stuff;
}
```

var currentage is never redefined so your if(); statement never initiates.

Answer (score 0):

Your > should be < in `if(currentage > age)`. You want to change current age if age is higher, not the other way around.